# Computer can not connect to some wifi networks

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-8.1

I have an laptop running Windows 8.1 X64 and when I connect it to my WiFi network works like a charm but in my girlfriend's house it connect's but I can not access to the internet and in the same network with my phone I have internet

Excluded so far:

- Drivers (installed and reinstalled)
- Windows OS (reinstalled)
- WiFi Interface (tested with another one over USB and the result still the same)
- Router (Only the laptop does not work)

My Router is an D-Link and her's is an Thomson...

Any Help?

Comment: What 802.11 mode do both networks support and what modes does the wireless adapter support?

Comment: The laptop supports B/G my home network B/G/N and the other network B/G

Comment: brand and model number would be nice

Comment: Can you ping the router?  What does the Windows "Network and Connection Centre" say?  Are you getting an ip from the router? Can you ping your computer from another (your girlfriend's?) computer?

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure about Windows 8, but with 7 I've always had problems with initial connections to networks where the popup that asks "What kind of network is this?" never pops up and blocks all connectivity in the meantime.

Your phone would never receive such a popup, which is why it works.

That's what this sounds like to me. Perhaps someone else knows how to actually get that prompt to pop up?

Comment: I will try to forget the network and connect again... Maybe that solves...

Comment: Forget the network and reconnect didn't worked... And does not ask for password :X I've tryed using command line and settings

Comment: That's not quite what I was referring to. When connecting to a new network, do you normally get a popup that asks you "What kind of network is this? Home, Work or Public?" If so, do you or did you ever get this popup at your gf's house?

Comment: Not it didn't...